# Barcode reading values to textbox?

Tags: php, ajax, barcode

I have a barcode scanner which reads the string of the barcode and displays in the active text box. also there is no consistent end character to the barcode, or standard length (I have 5 diffent length sizes. 16,17,18,19,20). I need to extract values from scanned data. so extracting values also depend on the barcode length.

So how would I go about firing a method when the WHOLE string has been read in?

Im using php and ajax to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{



    $("#bcode").focus();
    //prevents autocomplete in some browsers
    $("#bcode").attr('autocomplete', 'off').keyup(function(event)
    {

                var name = $("#bcode").val();



            $("#status").empty();
            if(name.length > 17 ) `// need to check all possible length values like this`
            {
                selectAll();

                $("#status").html('<img align="absmiddle" src="images/loading.gif" /> Checking availability...').show();




     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "namecheck.php",
                    data : "bcode=" + name,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#status").html(msg).show();
                    }
                    });

        }
        else
        {
            $("#status").html('').addClass('err').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I did some work with a card swiper, there are similar challenges there.  The data comes in a rapid burst, but there isn't a consistent "end-of-data" string being sent.  The solution is to use `setTimeout` and wait - when the input stops, then you fire your processing code.

Depending on your hardware, the amount of waiting you'll want to do varies.  Experiment with this code, to adjust the wait time, simply adjust the `duration` argument of `setTimeout`.  I've started it on 500ms - that works pretty well for the card swipers.  Forgive me if there are any minor wobbles in my code here - I am not a jQuery guy :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bcode")
        .focus()
        .attr('autocomplete', 'off')
        .keyup(function(event){
            // if the timer is set, clear it
            if (barcode_watch_timer !== false)
                clearTimeout(barcode_watch_timer);
            // set the timer to wait 500ms for more input
            barcode_watch_timer = setTimeout(function () {
                process_barcode_input();
            }, 500);
            // optionally show a status message
            //$("#status").html('waiting for more input...').show();
            // return false so the form doesn't submit if the char is equal to "enter"
            return false;
        });
});

var barcode_watch_timer = false;
function process_barcode_input() {
    // if the timer is set, clear it
    if (barcode_watch_timer !== false)
        clearTimeout(barcode_watch_timer);

    // grab the value, lock and empty the field
    var name = $("#bcode").val();
    $("#bcode").attr('disabled', true);

    // empty the status message
    $("#status").empty();

    // add a loading message
    $("#status").html('<img align="absmiddle" src="images/loading.gif" /> Checking availability...').show();
    // send the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "namecheck.php",
        data : "bcode=" + name,
        success: function(msg) {
            // unlock the field, show a success status
            $("#bcode").attr('disabled', false);
            $("#status").html(msg).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've worked with a few barcode scanners, and they've always included carriage return/newline at the end of input.  Are there really models out there that don't do this?  If you open up a text editor and scan a few barcodes, they all get appended together in a single line?

Comment: I can't speak for barcode scanners, but the card swipers I was working with had variations.  There's an input standard, so they're SUPPOSED to follow a proscribed format.  In practice, sometimes the end-of-input character gets dropped, cheaper models of reads have internal buffer overruns... the whole thing is kind of janky. Especially when coupling this kind of hardware with Javascript, you've got to loosely box your hardware in, but be ready for things to rattle around a little.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be a text area?

The last barcode reader I used always ended with a newline.  If you are inputing into a `<input type="text"/>` the return char will likely try to submit the form, and you can use an onSubmit to capture the event and process your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try observe the field with code by interval

Example

```
setInterval(function() {
    var value = $("#code").val(),
        prev_value = $("#code").attr("prev_value");

    if (prev_value == value) {// compare with prevent value for detecting canges
        console.log("value is not changed");
        return;
    }
    //if (value.length < 17) {
        //exeption
        // or reset value $("#code").val(prev_value);
        //return;
    //}
    if (value[value.length-1] == "\n") {// check last symbol
        console.log(value);// Do something with you code eg send by AJAX
    }
    $("#code").attr("prev_value", value); // save current value for compare later
}, 1000 );
```